# How do I enable my AWS Lambda function to write to Firehose?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have an AWS Lambda function that should write to a Firehose. However, when I make a `PutRecordBatchRequest` it will time-out and fail to write to the Firehose.

The function is in a VPC. I have attached a policy to the lambda's role to allow access:

```hcl
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "firehose:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.my_firehose.arn}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

*Note I am using Terraform, so solution in HCL are appreciated.*

**How do I get this to work?**

Comment: When an AWS Lambda function is connected to a VPC, it will not have direct access to the Internet. To grant such access, you will need either:

A NAT Gateway in a public subnet, with matching Route tables, or
A VPC Endpoint in the VPC for the desired service - If you are using VPC Endpoint - you may want to  configure the security groups for your lamda function correctly

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you put the Lambda function in a VPC? Does it need to communicate with resources in the VPC? If not, simply detach it from the VPC.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes it connects to RDS etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an `aws_vpc_endpoint`.

This allows the lambda inside of the VPC to communicate with the AWS services, which are outside the VPC. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/vpc.html.

```hcl
resource "aws_security_group" "firehose_endpoint" {
  name   = "firehose-endpoint"
  vpc_id = aws_default_vpc.default.id
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "firehose_endpoint" {
  vpc_id              = aws_default_vpc.default.id
  vpc_endpoint_type   = "Interface"
  service_name        = "com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.kinesis-firehose"
  security_group_ids  = [ aws_security_group.firehose_endpoint.id ]
  private_dns_enabled = true

  subnet_ids = [
    aws_default_subnet.subnet_a.id,
    aws_default_subnet.subnet_b.id
  ]

  policy  = <<EOF
      {
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Sid": "Firehose-full-access",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "firehose:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
          }
        ]
      }
    EOF
}
```

You will of course need to tailor your policy, subnets etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either set up internet access as suggested or AWS Privatelink as in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/vpc.html

Comment: I have tried following those docs but clearly have missed something in my Terraform scripts.

Comment: Try to do it manually without terraform perhaps its a security group issue? You can always look at the VPC Flow logs to see where the traffic is reaching or failing to reach